# R tabular function: Unrecognized entry 'mean'

Tags: r, tabular

I'm trying to create a descriptive statistics table with the following code:

```
tabular(time ~ ((n = 1) + (var_1 + var_2 + var_3)*(mean + sd + min + max)),
                 data = df1)
```

R gives me the following error:

> Error in term2table(rows[[i]], cols[[j]], data, n) : 
>     Unrecognized entry 'mean'

Interestingly, if I remove mean from the code (only leave sd, min and max), everything works perfectly.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you are using the `tables` package.  I would guess you have your own definition for a function or variable called `mean`, and it is hiding the one in the `base` package.  However, I can't reproduce your error, because as @jogo said, we don't have a complete example.